# Leading number in model name / form name

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've recently started playing with angular, and found out this behavior with naming elements.
Using angular with bootstrap, i create the following view:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" name="1testForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>test
        </legend>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
                <input ng-model="inputValue" class-name="form-control"
                    input-value="box4"
                    required="true" />
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button id="btnSubmit"
                    ng-disabled="1testForm.$invalid"
                    class="btn btn-primary">
                    Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The behavior is simple, if the input field is empty, the form is not valid and the ng-disabled disables the submit button.
The peculiar thing is that if my form is named with a leading number, the condition fails.
If i remove the 1, the button becomes disabled.

I was just curious about why this happens and maybe a reference to related naming conventions, as I suspect this might not be angular related. Thanks.

Comment: When you add the trailing `1` are you also adding the trailing `1` to `ng-disabled="1testForm1.$invalid"`?

Comment: Uh, this is embarassing. Rather than trailing, I meant leading. Bad english, i apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [HTML 4 conventions](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2) for the name attribute:

```
ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and
may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), 
hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
```

If you use name="testForm1" and ng-disabled="testForm1.$invalid" (the number is a suffix), it should work fine.

Comment: This is for HTML4, 5 can be whatever.

Comment: Well he might be using HTML4

Comment: I see, I wonder if it affects javascript in general, or if it's angular related thing in this particular case. Anyways thanks for the reference.